# Mimic linux xxd command in C

Tags: c, linux, for-loop, formatting, xxd

I have the problem mostly solved, I just can't get the last line to be formatted correctly with spaces. I am close, but I need another set of eyes on this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

const int MAX_CHAR = 16;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //command line argument for filename
    char *fileName = argv[1];
    
    //open file and check for validity
    FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("The file was not opened correctly\n");
        return -1;
    }

    
    char line[MAX_CHAR];   //array to store characters
    int lineCount = 0;     //counter for hexadecimal line display
    int charCount = 0;     //counter for spacing of hex ascii values
    int breakIndex = MAX_CHAR;  //integer to save what index the array is stopped at EOF
    
    //cycle through every 16 characters
    while(!feof(file)) 
    {
        //read 16 characters
        for(int i = 0; i<breakIndex ; i++)
        {
            
            line[i]=fgetc(file);
            if (feof(file))
            {
                breakIndex = i;
                line[i]='\0';
                break;
            }
        }
       
        //print line count in hexadecimal
        printf("%.08x: ",lineCount);
        
        //print hexadecimal for each character
        for(int i = 0; i<breakIndex; i++)
        {
            printf("%.02x",line[i]);
            charCount++;
            if(charCount % 2 == 0)
            {
                printf(" ");
            }
        }

        //spaces for formatting output
        if(breakIndex == MAX_CHAR)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        else
        {
            int spaces = (MAX_CHAR - breakIndex) * 2 ;
            //printf("----%d-----",spaces);
            for(int i = 0 ; i< spaces ; i++)    
            {
                printf(" ");
            }
        }
        
        //print actual characters
        for(int i = 0; i<breakIndex ; i++)
        {
            if(!isprint(line[i]))
            {
                line[i]= '.';
            }
        }
        line[16] = '\0';
        printf("%s",line);
        printf("\n");

        //increment line count
        lineCount+=16;
    }

    //close file
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

My problem lies in the "spaces for formatting output section of code. I have accounted for the hexadecimal digits but I can't formulate how to account for the other spaces needed.

[this is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Yz7h.png)
[this is the actual xxd output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyV4C.png) 
I need this to work for any length file given

Comment: You're very close, great job! Aside from the formatting issue you are asking about, you have another issue to be aware of: `line[16] = '\0';` -  This is bad! You are writing a null byte to `line[16]` but the size of the `line` array is 16. The array is accessed using zero-indexing, so you're actually writing to the 17th position of the array, which is undefined behavior and will most likely write beyond the bounds of the array.

Comment: [Why is “while( !feof(file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/2505965)

Comment: `fopen(NULL, "r")` is UB. Check the validity of `argv[1]` before using it (e.g., `argc > 1`).

Answer (score 1):

To largely summarize the comments:

```
const int MAX_CHAR = 16;
char line[MAX_CHAR];
```

`line` is an array ([variable-length](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array#Variable-length_arrays)) of length 16, with the valid indicies *[0, 15]*.

`line[16] = '\0'` indexes a *seventeenth* element, that does not exist. This is out-of-bounds array access, which invokes [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

`while(!feof(file))` is [always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/2505965) - avoid it. Test the results of your I/O functions directly (important: use `int` type to hold the value returned by `fgetc`, if you want to reliably test for `EOF`. See below.).

```
char *fileName = argv[1];
FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "r");
```

If `argv[1]` is `NULL` (i.e., `argc < 2`), this also invokes [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior). (Additionally, [`xxd`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xxd) mimicry would involve reading from `stdin` if no input file is specified, but we can put that aside for now.)

---

Generally speaking, errors should be written to `stderr`.

If you would like to avoid null-terminating your buffer, you can print up to a fixed amount of characters from a buffer with `printf("%.*s", (int) n, buffer)`.

---

One important thing to note is that the `%x` [specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) expects an `unsigned int` argument, and `printf` arguments are subject to [integer promotions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion).

`char` is a unique type, distinct from `signed char` or `unsigned char`, and its signed-ness is implementation defined. This uniqueness is the same reason you cannot use `char` to reliably test for the *negative* value of `EOF` (as in the return value from `fgetc`), as the value may become indistinguishable from another valid value in the event that `char` is *unsigned*.

Use `unsigned char` for your buffer (and `%hhx` for your specifier, if you want to be super-correct about it).

(*Without this, you may get large hexadecimal values from *signed* bytes in your file. Think binary.*)

`lineCount` should also be `unsigned int` (or use `size_t`, and `%zx`).

---

As for spacing, the total amount of characters to write per line for the hexadecimal pairs *block* is

```
(MAX_CHAR) * 2 + (MAX_CHAR / 2) + (MAX_CHAR & 1)
```

(*Assuming integer division.*)

Broken down, the format is:

```
[file offset][:][space][hexadecimal octet pairs, delimiters][space][printable data][newline]
```

That said, a simple way to do this is to is to always iterate `MAX_CHAR` times, and decide if you are printing a 2-character hex octet, or two spaces when you run out of valid octets. A delimiting space is printed on every odd-iteration **or** always on the final iteration.

Following this, a modified version of your example looks like:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_CHAR 16

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        fputs("Insufficient arguments.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    char *fileName = argv[1];
    FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "r");

    if (!file) {
        perror(fileName);
        return 1;
    }

    unsigned lineCount = 0;
    int reading = 1;

    while (reading) {
        unsigned char line[MAX_CHAR] = { 0 };
        int bytes_read = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CHAR; i++) {
            int ch = fgetc(file);

            if (EOF == ch) {
                reading = 0;
                break;
            }

            line[i] = ch;
            bytes_read++;
        }

        if (!bytes_read)
            break;

        printf("%08x: ", lineCount);

        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CHAR; i++) {
            if (i < bytes_read) {
                printf("%02hhx", line[i]);

                if (!isprint(line[i])) {
                    line[i] = '.';
                }
            } else {
                printf("  ");
            }

            if (i % 2 != 0 || i == MAX_CHAR - 1) {
                printf(" ");
            }
        }

        putchar(' ');
        printf("%.*s\n", (int) bytes_read, line);
        lineCount += MAX_CHAR;
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```

Alternatively, this can be done with `fread`, reading *chunks* of data:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define CHUNK_SIZE 16

static void xxd_default(FILE *file)
{
    unsigned char buffer[CHUNK_SIZE];
    size_t offset = 0;
    size_t bytes;

    while ((bytes = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof buffer, file))) {
        printf("%08zx: ", offset++ * sizeof buffer);

        for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof buffer; i++) {
            if (i < bytes)
                printf("%02hhx", buffer[i]);
            else
                fputs("  ", stdout);

            /* every other, always last */
            if (i & 1 || sizeof buffer - 1 == i)
                putchar(' ');
        }

        putchar(' ');

        for (size_t i = 0; i < bytes; i++)
            putchar(isprint(buffer[i]) ? buffer[i] : '.');

        putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *file = stdin;

    if (argc > 1) {
        file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

        if (!file) {
            perror(argv[1]);
            return 1;
        }
    }

    xxd_default(file);

    if (argc > 1)
        return 0 != fclose(file);
}
```